# Is it possible to initialize vector to be copy of another with appended extra elements

Tags: c++, vector

I have class with a static `std::vector<string>`. I would like to derive from it, and extend the vector in the derived class.

Something like this:

```
class A {
  static std::vector<std::string> column_names;
};
std::vector<std::string> A::column_names = {"col1", "col2"};

class B : public A{
  static std::vector<std::string> column_names;
};
std::vector<std::string> B::column_names = {A::column_names, "col2"}; // <-- *
```

Is something like `*` possible?

My rationale is that, I would like to initialize the `B::column_names` with out delegating it into constructor with some static flag. `B` will always be some extension to `A` so its natural to append the columns to it.

Edit: Also I don't plan on changing of column_names during run-time. It can be defined as `const` if that helps with anything.

Comment: But `B` doesn't derive from `A`?

Comment: @Nim my mistake. I forgot to type it. Edited, though I think it actually doesn't matter in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try having a static function in `B` which returns the vector with the correct values, for example..

```
class B
{
  static std::vector<std::string> initial()
  {
    auto v = A::column_names;
    v.push_back("col2");
    return v;
  }
};
// Now initialize column_names from this function...
std::vector<std::string> B::column_names = B::initial();
```

Comment: Looks like good concise and probably fast idea; and works with `const static` too. Btw. I cleaned up your code and accepted. Thanks for this suggestion. I guess `auto v(A::column_names);` would be equivalent.